# Typescript dynamic class methods

Tags: typescript

### Problem

How can one add type checking to a dynamically created class method?

### Example

Given a very simple `Property` class.

```
class Property {
  value: any;
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string, value: any) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value
  }
}
```

and an `Entity` class

```
class Entity {
  name: string;
  properties: Property[];


  constructor(name: string, properties: Property[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.properties = properties;

    this.properties.forEach((p: Property, index: number) => {
      this[p.name] = (value: string): any => {
        if (value) {
          this.properties[index].value = value;
        }
        return this.properties[index].value;
      }
    }, this);
  }
}
```

Important part: `this[p.name] = function ...`  (we don't know the name of the method at "transpile" time).

We get the following error when transpiling to javascript:

```
var car = new domain.Entity(
  'car',
  [
    new domain.Property('manufacturer', 'Ford'),
    new domain.Property('model', 'Focus')
  ]
);

car.model() // error TS2339: Property 'model' does not exist on type 'Entity'.
```

I know that this is a uncommon use of classes as different instances of `Entity` will have different methods defined. Is there a way to get rid of the error, i.e. **typescript is able to identify the proper interface per instance**, or at least **silent the error**?

### Notes

This is valid javascript and one could use it in the following manner:

```
var car = new domain.Entity(
  'car',
  [
    new domain.Property('manufacturer', 'Ford'),
    new domain.Property('model', 'Focus')
  ]
);

car.model()          // 'Focus'
car.model('Transit') // 'Transit'
```

I'm aware that this has been asked on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242034/typescript-dynamic-properties-and-methods), but this case is slightly different as the method name is also defined at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dynamic properties you want to access then use the **any** type to bypass type checks for the variable. You can either declare the variable with the **any** type from the get go, or use the type assertion operator (**as**) at some later point. So here are some possible variants:

```
var car: any = new domain.Entity(...);
car.model();

var car = new domain.Entity(...) as any;
car.model();

var car = new domain.Entity(...);
(car as any).model();
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, this solves the transpilation error. I didn't know about the `as` operator, it's very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Add this type (just needed once):

```
interface Prop<T> {
    (): T;
    (value: T): T;
}
```

then you can write this for each shape you create:

```
interface Car extends Entity {
    model: Prop<string>;
    manufacturer: Prop<string>;
}
let car = <Car>new Entity('car', [/*...*/]);
car.model(32); // Error
let x = car.model(); // x: string
```

Comment: I should maybe add this to the question, but my goal is to be able to create new `Entity` instances (with different properties) without having to change any code (e.g. from a JSON file). For that reason, this won't work, unfortunately. This is called Adaptive Object-Model if anyone is interested http://www.adaptiveobjectmodel.com/WICSA3/ArchitectureOfAOMsWICSA3.pdf

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before. Documentation link?